# Changing color of textview in android

Tags: android

**listview_item_for_images.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantNameImageTopID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/TextColorForTextAboveImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Here i am placing a textview on top of image and it is displayed in a listview

I got the successful output

but

On if i change the text color to white in xml properties and compile 
I get below as error

**log**::

```
09-28 15:53:22.065: I/MemoryCache(2451): MemoryCache will use up to 8.0MB
09-28 15:53:22.445: D/dalvikvm(2451): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 307K, 50% free 2966K/5895K, external 2130K/2137K, paused 102ms
09-28 15:53:22.465: I/MemoryCache(2451): cache size=47000 length=1
09-28 15:53:22.715: I/MemoryCache(2451): cache size=111500 length=2
09-28 15:53:22.795: I/MemoryCache(2451): cache size=168620 length=3
09-28 15:53:22.795: I/MemoryCache(2451): cache size=237060 length=4
09-28 15:53:24.685: D/dalvikvm(2451): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 422K, 53% free 2805K/5895K, external 2709K/2713K, paused 82ms
09-28 15:53:26.855: I/MemoryCache(2451): MemoryCache will use up to 8.0MB
09-28 15:53:26.875: W/ResourceType(2451): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
09-28 15:53:26.885: D/AndroidRuntime(2451): Shutting down VM
09-28 15:53:26.885: W/dalvikvm(2451): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at com.project.findmybuffet.ListViewAdapterForImages.getView(ListViewAdapterForImages.java:60)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     ... 45 more
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060000 a=-1 r=0x7f060000}
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1804)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:649)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:337)
09-28 15:53:26.945: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):     ... 48 more
```

Comment: if you want to add TextView on top of ImageView then you should use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout

Comment: but i did get output using relative layout with default color...... is this the reason i am not able to change color ? .... i get error only on changing the color !

Comment: you will get the output but i doubt if it is the right way to achieve what you are trying to achieve !!

Comment: I have defined in styles as     <colorname="TextColorForTextAboveImage">#FFFFFF</color>    .... then referencing from xml

Comment: IF using frame layout is the right way .....can you please edit the xml i posted as per ur suggestion in your answer !

Comment: just change the RelativeLayout to FrameLayout , it should work !!

Comment: `RelativeLayout` has nothing to do with the error. As for me, both `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout` are fine for this scenario. The issue is in color resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, but according to this output message

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path)
```

My bet is that `@color/TextColorForTextAboveImage` is not correctly defined. A color resource should look like this.-

```
<color name="TextColorForTextAboveImage">#FF0000</color>
```

**EDIT**

Definitely you have a typo: `colorname` should be `color name` (notice the space)

Comment: I found out what was the error..... I defined the colour attribute value in valuesV14 insted of just values folder ! .... your inpur helped ! ... thanks !