# Android Crash on EditText long press

Tags: android

I ran into a particularly strange crash regarding the long click on a EditText which has some text in it (works fine otherwise). This happens systematically.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010036 a=3}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:3532)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:343)
        at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3149)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTextAppearance(AppCompatTextView.java:56)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.initTitle(ActionBarContextView.java:139)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.setTitle(ActionBarContextView.java:115)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.StandaloneActionMode.setTitle(StandaloneActionMode.java:60)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.setTitle(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:63)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode(Editor.java:3268)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3039)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:155)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onCreateActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1644)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionModeFromWindow(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:748)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:642)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.startAsSupportActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:74)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.onWindowStartingActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:58)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2651)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4756)
        at android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode(Editor.java:1831)
        at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1060)
        at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:10149)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19433)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I saw a few posts on SO but so far no luck. I must also mention that this happens on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 API 19 as it seems to have some already marked [issues](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=970081) but the ticket appears as fixed.

Here is some code for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_login">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mServerUrlButton"
    style="@style/OkButton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mServerUrlEditText"
    style="@style/LoginField"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mServerUrlButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/mServerUrlButton"
    android:hint="@string/server_url_placeholder"
    android:inputType="textUri"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
</style>

<style name="OkButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/confirm_button_height</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_login_button</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/ok_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Field" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_login_field</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginField" parent="Field">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/login_field_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/login_field_height</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

This does nots come from my hint color or background drawable as I already tried to disable them one by one to see where it fails. Even without any customization (just width and height that are required) it still crashes.

Still here is my colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="green">#015b27</color>
<color name="pink">#a10453</color>
<color name="gray">#707070</color>
<color name="light_gray">#B6B6B6</color>

<color name="light_green">#8AC97A</color>
<color name="light_pink">#FF84C2</color>

<color name="white_alpha">#DDFFFFFF</color>
<color name="black_alpha">#80000000</color>
</resources>
```

And my drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black" />

</shape>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing color of textview in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065870/changing-color-of-textview-in-android)

Comment: Could have been that but I checked my colors and there is nothing wrong. I edited my post in that manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally found out the culprit... It appears that calling **?attr/colorControlNormal** on any **android:textColor[*]** property was unable to find the color reference in my styles.xml. I had to define first the text primary color to then define the secondary color from the primary using, using the "android" namespace.

So my AppTheme.Base now look like:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
</style>
```